# Java fail-over framework/library

Tags: java, high-availability, failover, low-latency

Is there any framework/library that takes care of active/passive failover? Ideally it should be fast, lightweight and embeddable. I've found a few but they don't quite fit the criteria...

- http://zookeeper.apache.org/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jheartbeat/
- http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2002/jw-0315-heart.html

Comment: What is the criteria? Which criteria don't quite fit?

Comment: @peterlawrey fast, lightweight and embeddable

Comment: Were you able to find and framework suiting your requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/building-dynamic-fail-over-java-servers/184404846

Its embeddable; lightweight...fast enough

It is a very old article from dr dobbs and relies on UDP which might cause you trouble depending on your network topology.